# Ĉiu komprenebla frazo en Esperanto estas ĝusta Esperanto - kie tio estas skribita?

Tags: quotes, fundamento

Mi certas ke mi legis tion en Die Zamenhofstraße, kaj ke tio estis skribita de Zamenhof. Mi nun serĉis enrete sed mi ankoraŭ ne trovis la frazon.
Ĉu iu povas helpi min?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la *Bulonja Deklaracio* estas skribite, ke

> ". . . ĉiu Esperantisto havas la rajton esprimi en tia maniero, kiun li trovas la plej ĝusta, tiel same, kiel estas farate en ĉiu alia lingvo."

Eble tiu estas la inspiro por tiu frazo!

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deklaracio_pri_Esperanto